# Approximation of Fourier Transform by DFT

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis

Let us say that we have some Schwartz function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$. The Fourier transform of $f$ is given by:
$$
\hat{f} (\xi ) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{-2\pi i x \xi } \mathrm{d}x
$$
In what sense does the discrete Fourier transform, defined by:

$$
\hat{x}(k) = \sum_{j = 1}^{N - 1}x(j)e^{\frac{-2\pi i}{N} kj}
$$

approximate the Fourier transform of some function?
Note that I am not really looking for a rigorous explanation or something about modes of convergence, rather, why intuitively (say through the use of Riemann sums) the above can serve as a numerical approximation of a standard Fourier transform.

Comment: The sum isn't a good approximation at all. This is demonstrated in Numerical Recipes in C++.

Comment: I see. What then is the the point of the DFT if not to serve as an approximation to the FT? Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Many other purposes. Trigonometric interpolation is one: https://github.com/boostorg/math/pull/229

Comment: But you're right: DFT is used for FT approximation, it's just a very bad approximation and (say) Ooura's method for the Fourier transform is better.

Comment: Also signal processing: Take DFT of signal, damp out high frequencies (assumed to be noise), then take inverse DFT.

Comment: In most real life scenarios, we don't have access to continuous signals. Every signal we capture is sampled. That gives rise to the field of digital signal processing. Think about every bit of information on the internet, in electronics, communication, storage etc... Signals that are sampled are represented with discrete time, and the Discrete Fourier Transform is used to compute those discrete signals' spectrum.

Comment: @StefanLafon that makes sense. But are signals (in reality) analog? Note I'm not trying to ask something philosophical, i.e. about the continuous or discrete nature of time/space, but are discrete samples the whole story, or are they an approximation to something?

Comment: I'm assuming they're analog for most of them.  Well except once they're digitized they're discrete.